# I am wondering what is happening in c while predicate?

Tags: c

I saw some C while loop with predicate as while(*ptr), and ptr is usually of char * type, how does this work? Does this mean "while()" will also accept values other than 1 or 0 as predicates?

Comment: while(*ptr) where ptr is a string will fail when that string happens to not be null terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, any non-zero value is considered "true", so `while (*ptr)` will loop as long as `*ptr` is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let's expand on this a little.

The while syntax in C means "if the conditional is true, do the body; then if it's still true, do the body again."

As casablanca notes, any value of 0 in C is "false"; any non-zero value is "true".  (It's worth considering why they chose that; you can get a good hint if you look at the PDP-11 instruction set.)  So you can expand that out to

```
 while /* the expression *ptr is nonzero*/)
     /* do this */
```

The expression `*prt` means simply `whatever is at the address stored in ptr`.

The usual sort of code where this pattern is used is in string processing.  Say we have

```
 char myString[] = "Hello, world!" ; // remember char myString[] is equivalent
                                     // to char * myString in C

 char * ptr = myString;              // note ptr points to myString[0]

 while(*ptr){
   putc(*ptr);
   ptr ++;
 }
```

Now as long as ptr points to a character in the string, it's non-zero, and the loop continued.  but by convention in C, all strings end with a NUL, ie, a byte-wide 0.  So
when the loop reaches that last NUL, *ptr is 0, and the loop ends.

You could write it more tersely by

```
 char * ptr = myString;
 while(*ptr) putc(ptr++);
```

Puzzle: Can you write this more tersely still?

Comment: Terse C is evil - don't tempt people :P

Answer (score 0):

In C anything zero is considered false and anything else is considered true.  That code is essentially saying "while ptr isn't null", which given null terminated string is a common way to walk though a string.

Comment: Exactly wrong. 0 is not true. Anything 0 is false, anything else is true.

Comment: Indeed, embarassing.  I was thinking process edit codes and success. :(

Answer (score 0):

C expects the condition of a `while()` clause to be an integer.  If the integer is zero, the while loop exits, otherwise it executes it's body and evaluates the condition again.  A wide variety of things count in C as integers, including characters.  the character `'\0'` (the null character) is equal to the integer `0`

Answer (score 0):

In C, any non-zero value is considered true.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idiom used to iterate through a C-string since C-strings are defined to be NUL terminated.  This works because the NUL character `\0` has a value of zero and as you may know, a value of zero will cause the `while()` loop to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Since in C the most common string type is the null terminated string it makes sense to loop like so sometimes

```
while(*ptr)
{
    printf("%c", *ptr);
    ptr++;
}
```

Which essentially moves from character to character in a character array until the null character is encountered. Of course this is bad form since `'\0'`, `null` and `0` need not be the same on a given system, but works on 99% of environments.

Comment: No, this is guaranteed to work 100%. A null-character terminator will always be zero with regards to a boolean construct. A NULL pointer may not physically contain all zero bits but will always logically equate to 0.